# Как сделать фото прозрачным постепенно?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Т.е у меня 2 слоя друг на друге. Сделал так, чтобы при наведении мышки на верхний элемент, этот верхний элемент поднимается плавно наверх. Как бы крышка открывается. Но хочется чтобы когда она поднимается так она постепенно и с верхней, и с нижней стороны постепенно становилась прозрачной, как бы не проходила границу элемента 300х300.

Допустим поднималась на 80 пикселей и при этом постепенно становилась прозрачной 40 пикселей сверху и 40 - снизу, одновременно уменьшалась

[Как вот ТУТ](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать без дополнительной картинки. А с помощью полупрозрачного бордера.
Поверх помещаете див. Весь эффект производится, играясь с верхним и нижним бордерами и высотой дива. Допустим есть картинка 150x150. Помещаем поверх див с высотой 0 и верхним и нижним бордерами по 75px. Т.о. они перекрывают всю картинку. Далее плавно увеличиваем высоту дива и пропорционально уменьшаем бордеры. К сожалению нет времени писать код. Можете посмотреть как работает редактирование личных фотографий Вконтакте например. Кроп использует именно эту хитрость. Всё просто и очень даже кроссбраузерно. Работает до IE8, проверено.

Comment: вы прошли по ссылке? может там другой трюк используется. Можете посмотреть?